# Return view not picking up new view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to change the view that on of my controllers points to however this is not picking up the amendment. The following is the code I am trying to use;

```
// GET: UserDemographics/Create
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View("Manage");
}
```

And my views folders look like below:

[image]

My understanding is that `View` tries to check for the same name as the method but I may be wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the name of your controller?  Is it `UserDemographics`?  If not, it should be - or rename your folder name to match the controller that contains your `Manage.cshtml` view

Comment: Nothing wrong in your code. This should work perfectly

Comment: Please can you let me know why you marked a question that didn't contain your answer as the correct answer.  It's not going to help anyone viewing this question in the future.

Comment: @Luke, Sure I have marked this below as my answer due to the comment left by yourself and Tushar, this made me realise where I was going wrong. You are correct however I did have to change my method in order to get this to work however at the time you had not posed the answer. Sorry for any confusion however.

Comment: Well you can always consider changing the correct answer, wink wink.  :0)  Or answer it yourself if you feel that the resolution can be more clearly expressed.  There's no point in checking the answer that isn't the answer to your question.  Questions on SO should be answered such that they are useful to people with the same problem.

Comment: The strange thing is Tom don't know what he is asking and @Luke don't even understand the question. But they are fighting for points. Tom created a view name that is different to action method name. And he want to return that view inside Create method. So there is nothing wrong with this. He can return any view from a method. Instead of calling this UserDemographics/Create he was calling UserDemographics/Manage. Even there is no Manage method he have in his question. That's why he was getting error. Luke don't worry for points. It will automatically reach u if u post a valid answer.

Comment: Ultimately Tom wasn't sure about the difference between configuring the view name in his action and the URL generated by convention by specifying the action name.  Hopefully the answer given clears this up both of these points for anyone reading in the future.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The view name specified within the `View()` method does not alter the path in the URL when making a request, it simply changes the name of the view that is rendered as a result of the request.

If you want the path to your action to be `/UserDemographics/Manage`, you would need to change the name of your Action method to `Manage`.

```
public class UserDemographics : Controller
{
    // Requested by /UserDemographics/Manage in the browser
    public ActionResult Manage()
    {
        // You don't HAVE to specify the view name here, Manage.cshtml will be rendered based on the convention.
        // However as mentioned this is best practice to specify the name.
        return View("Manage");
    }
}
```

This makes it so that there is no longer a need to specify the View name as it will be automatically selected from the Views folder by convention for that controller.

Comment: It is [best practice](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aspnetue/2010/09/17/best-practices-for-asp-net-mvc/) to explicitly name views in action methods.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong in your code. This should work perfectly

Your URL should be like this,

```
localhost:[Port Number]/userdemographics/Create
```

If you already hosted your project in a real domain, then you can replace `localhost:[Port Number]` with your domain name. For example,

```
www.example.com/userdemographics/Create
```